# Running multi file python apache beam with airflow Cloud Composer

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, airflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

I have a multi file python apache beam job that I want to run on Cloud Dataflow through airflow / cloud composer. My multi file job is designed following this recommendation https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#multiple-file-dependencies It works without any problem from CLI.
Now I want to run it through airflow and Cloud Composer. I tried to use https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#dataflowpythonoperator but it does not work. Probably I'm missing the right way to configure this operator. By the way I have no problem using this operator to run one file python apache beam jobs.

Comment: It might be related to the way how these multiple files are packaged, does this help? https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local